# Должна ли знать модель о текущем идентификаторе пользователя?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

Проблема:
В связи с тем, что многие таблицы в *БД* имеют `FK user_id`, то и работа с моделью без его участия невозможна. Т.е. в каждом *CRUD*-запросе мы имеем дополнительное условие `WHERE user_id = 1`, просто для того, чтобы текущий пользователь не имел доступа к записям, отличным от своих.

В *Eloquent ORM* удобно работать только с *PK*-идентификатором.

```
//красиво, коротко, но юзер может запросить чужую запись.
$post = Post::find($postId);
$post->content = 'text';
$post->save();
```

А конструкции вида вообще использует *Query Builder*:

```
Post::where('user_id', $userId)->where('id', $postId)->update([...]);
```

Чтобы не лишиться плюшек *ORM* (например, `events`), пока выкручивался так:

```
$post = Post::where('user_id', $userId)->where('id', $postId)->first();
// или $post = Post::fistByAttributes(['user_id' => $userId, 'id' => $postId]);
$post->content = 'long saving :(';
$post->save();
```

Все-таки длинновато.

Решение состоит в том, чтобы создать `trait`, который будет подмешивать свою реализацию `find`-метода. Но в таком случае, мне придется сделать список полей и их значений, которые будут добавлены в условие выборки.

Проблема в том, что получение `id` текущего пользователя `Auth::id()` в модели может быть идеологически неверным. Как, к примеру, использование `global` в *php*.

Из минусов - через эту модель теперь нельзя делать запросы без обязательного условия `where user_id = 1`;

Какие минусы данного решения вы видите? Вы сталкивались с подобным? Что на ваш взгляд можно сделать, решая эту проблему?

Answer (score 2):

В Laravel и Eloquent ORM есть такая прекрасная вещь как [отношения](https://laravel.ru/docs/v4/eloquent#%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).
Достаточно прописать в классе User.php:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

(пример для версии 4)

и далее можно будет доставать записи пользователя через `$user->posts()` вместо `Post::where('user_id', $userId)`

Но на самом деле проверку является ли юзер автором поста лучше делать так

```
$post = Post::find($id);
if ($post->author !== Auth::id())
{
    return false;
}
```